# Streamlit: buttons side-by-side in a sidebar

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to have two buttons side-by-side in the Streamlit sidebar. I search for this question and found this solution:

```
col1, col2 = st.sidebar.columns(2)
with col1:
    st.sidebar.button("Add")
with col2:
    st.sidebar.button("Remove")
```

Unfortunately, it does absolutely nothing for me: the resulting buttons are located in separate rows, not in separate columns. Note that there is enough width of side bar for both buttons to be displayed side-by-side.

Why this does not work and is there some other solution? Streamlit version 1.29.0.

Comment: Just remove the `sidebar.` before button and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code that I think can useful for you.

```
import streamlit as st

col1, col2 = st.sidebar.columns(2)

button1 = col1.button('Button 1')
button2 = col2.button('Button 2')
```

My result likes this bellow.

[image: Result]